# Counting appropriate number of subarrays in an array excluding some specific pairs?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Let's say, I have an array like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

And given pair is `(2,3)`, then number of possible subarrays that don't have (2,3) present in them will be,,

```
1. 1
2. 2
3. 3
4. 4
5. 5
6. 1 2
7. 3 4
8. 4 5
9. 3 4 5
```

So, the answer will be `9`.

Obviously, there can be more of such pairs.

Now, one method that I thought of is of O(n^2) which involves finding all such elements of maximum length `n`. Can I do better? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean contiguous subarrays (If not, your example is wrong, ex [1, 3])?

Comment: can there be duplicate numbers in that array?

Comment: @Amit, a subarray obviously means contiguous elements.

Comment: @Sumurai8, if the original array contains duplicate numbers and they form a subarray and are not part of the required pair, yes. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's see, this adhoc pseudocode should be O(n):

```
array = [1 2 3 4 5]
pair = [2 3]
length = array.length
n = 0
start = 0

while (start < length)
{
    # Find next pair

    pair_pos = start
    while (pair_pos < length) and (array[pair_pos,pair_pos+1] != pair)   # (**1)
    {
        pair_pos++
    }

    # Count subarrays

    n += calc_number_of_subarrays(pair_pos-start)  # (**2)

    # Continue after the pair

    start = pair_pos+2
}

print n
```

Note **1: This seems to involve a loop inside the outer loop. Since every element of the array is visited exactly once, both loops together are O(n). In fact, it is probably easy to refactor this to use only one while loop.

Note **2: Given an array of length l, there are l+(l-1)+(l-2)+...+1 subarrays (including the array itself). Which is easy to calculate in O(1), there is no loop involved. c/f Euler. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to find which subarrays are in an array to know how many of them there are. Finding where the pair is in the array is at most 2(n-1) array operations. Then you only need to do a simple calculation with the two lengths you extract from that. The amount of subarrays in an array of length 3 is, for example, `3 + 2 + 1 = 6 = (n(n+1))/2`.

The solution uses that in a given array `[a, ..., p1, p2, ..., b]`, the amount of subarrays without the pair is the amount of subarrays for `[a, ..., p1]` + the amount of subarrays for `[p2, ..., b]`. If multiple of such pairs exist, we repeat the same trick on `[p2, ..., b]` as if it was the whole array.

```
function amount_of_subarrays ::
  index := 1
  amount := 0
  lastmatch := 0

  while length( array ) > index do
    if array[index] == pair[1] then
      if array[index+1] == pair[2] then
        length2 := index - lastmatch
        amount := amount + ((length2 * (length2 + 1)) / 2)
        lastmatch := index
      fi
    fi
    index := index + 1
  od

  //index is now equal to the length
  length2 := index - lastmatch
  amount := amount + ((length2 * (length2 + 1)) / 2)

  return amount
```

For an array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` with pair `[2, 3]`, `index` will be 2 when the two if-statements are true. `amount` will be updated to 3 and `lastmatch` will be updated to `2`. No more matches will be found, so `lastmatch` is 2 and `index` is 5. `amount` will be `3 + 6 = 9`.

Comment: How exactly will this work if the elements belonging to the pair found are not contiguous elements?

Comment: Then all your subarrays meet the requirement of not containing that exact pair.

Comment: If that isn't what you expect, please edit your question to clarify what your algorithm should do.